# Get taxonomy term of a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to get a custom "category" of a custom post type in wordpress. With no luck. Went through a whole bunch of answers, but none worked.

Here is the latest one i've tried

```
<?php   // Get terms for post
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'quizes' );
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 print $term->slug ;
 unset($term);
} } ?>
```

Comment: Does $post->ID return an ID and is quizes the name of the taxonomy?

Comment: It doesn't return anything...

Comment: If the post ID isn't returning anything then it's not going to work. You need to get the post ID first. There are several ways of getting the ID outside of the loop. One would be by adding `global $post;` to the top of your PHP file.